# How can I look at my character?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there a way I can inspect my character's face at any point in the game after creating it during the bathroom scene?

I am playing on PlayStation 4 and rotating with the right stick in 3rd-person view obviously does not show the face. I haven't found any mirrors or shiny objects to use the reflection either.

The reason for this is that I forgot what she looks like and also I want to share my monstrous creation with others but I have already left the vault!

Comment: Have you tried sitting down?

Comment: @aslum yes, i have later discovered that sitting down does the trick as you can rotate around your character when sitting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If rotating the camera does not suit your needs, you can get a close-up of your character's face by visiting a barber or plastic surgeon.  I don't have a comprehensive list of their locations on hand, but I do know there is a plastic surgeon in Diamond City.

I've heard that Codsworth can give you a haircut as well, but I have not confirmed this.

Comment: Up-voting this answer as it advises using the third person perspective like the other answers but also suggests an alternative method.
The barbers/plastic surgeons are probably as close to the original character design as you're going to get.

Comment: thank you! good call about barbers and plastic surgeons! i totally forgot about that -- have just started this one and it's been a while since fallout 3.

Comment: @DCShannon OP asked if there was a way to inspect his character's face.  Prior to the edit, he expressed dissatisfaction with the camera controls, so I offered an alternative.  I apologize if my answer offended you in some way.

Comment: I'm not offended, I'm just confused. It seems like a really poor answer, but apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: Diamond City also has a barber, as does Vault 81. Don't know about anywhere else yet. I must say though, I'm a bit disappointed at the plastic surgeon's whole-body view - you can't rotate the camera/PC like you can during first-time setup.

Comment: +1 here for not being dependent upon normal camera controls. But I would suggest adding in the camera instructions for completeness. Particularly, the OP sounded like they were missing the "put away your weapon" step. Also, a reminder about zoom controls (limited as they may be) would be handy here.

Answer (score 7):

If you put your weapon away (long press of the reload button), then rotating the right stick in 3rd person will be in freelook mode.

Answer (score 4):

On the PC you can hold down MOUSE 3 (middle mouse) while in third person mode to activate free look, allowing you to rotate around your character.

I'm unsure of the equivalent controls on console.

Comment: Adding to this, if you simply scroll the mousewheel backwards, it will put you into third-person mode which can be used to inspect your sculpting handiwork as well. Simply scroll in the opposite direction enough to return to first-person.

Answer (score 3):

If you switch to third-person view you can see your character.

If you put your weapon away, you can rotate the view around your character, to see their face.

If you hold down the perspective switch button, you can use the right stick to zoom in and out while rotating the view. Note that this creates problems when you're in a workshop area, as holding down the button will open up the workshop interface. If you've remapped your buttons, you may run into a bug where one of them doesn't work properly when you come out of the workshop interface. Pressing the switch-perspective button twice has fixed this for me, but the exact button may depend on how you've remapped your controller.

Comment: This is a solid answer but you should list the buttons/platform involved in order for readers to get the most out of this.

Comment: @Chase You can completely remap your controller, so the specific button isn't really important. I don't even remember what the defaults were.